# Reporting Error Due to Foreign Key Constraint in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, error-handling, foreign-keys

While deleting some rows from a table I am getting the following error in the inspect

> message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

I know the error is arising due to the failing foreign key. 
I would like to show an error message saying the deleting item is already used.

I am using Laravel 5.8, PHP 7.3, Mysql

Do anybody have any idea on this?

Comment: This is due to Primary Key and Foreign Key that you have set on tables, because of which its not allowing you to delete rows from related tables.

Comment: I know why the error arises. The problem I face is to report it and show the user the item they are trying to delete is already used in another place and hence cant be deleted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put code that is deleting rows in `try block` and handle exceptions in `catch block` like this.

```
try {
  // ...

} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
    var_dump($e->errorInfo);
}
```

`var_dump()` will give details about the exceptions, then you can manage it without failing the script.